# Criar autocomplete para Select Option com JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando fazer um autocomplete usando `select` com jquery mas não estou conseguindo. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim

```
function fillSelect(data) {
    //$('#usuarioSelected').empty();
    if (data['InvestidorMaster'].length > 0) {
        //$.each(data["InvestidorMaster"], function (i, cp) {
        //    $('#usuarioSelected').append('<option value="' + cp.id + '">' + cp.nome + '</option>');
        //});
       //fill select without autocomplete it works 

        //autocomplete
        var suggestions = [];
        $.each(data["InvestidorMaster"], function (i, cp) {
            suggestions.push({ 'value' : cp.id, 'label' : cp.nome});
        });
        $("#usuarioSelected").autocomplete({
            source: suggestions           
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar algum plugin que já faça isso pra vc? Segue o link da documentação de um: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: Vc quer criar a array com json?